# Logging into oracle db as a global user

Tags: oracle, delphi, ldap, oracleinternetdirectory

We are trying to shape up an old, 2 tier, Delphi based application. It originally uses database authentication, we'd like to transform the db user accounts to global users, so an OID server could perform the authentication instead of the database.

The Delphi program can no longer log into the database if the account is a global user. I'm trying to understand the login protocol, so far without results.

Similar thing happens with SQLDeveloper, I can't connect as a global user. SQLPlus however works with both kinds of users. We checked the information flow with Wireshark. When the dbserver asks back for a password, the SQLPlus sends it, while the SQLDeveloper doesn't send a password when attempting to connect as a global user.

The client sends the application name too in the login request. Is it possible that we have to store the client app name in the LDAP itself?

Comment: Which kind of authentication server are you using?

Comment: Database: Oracle Enterprise Edition 11gR2 x-64

Ldap: Oracle Internet Directory 10g (Oracle Internet Directory 101401)

Answer (score 1):

To connect to Oracle using OID, application must properly configure OCI (Oracle Call Interface). The data access components (which one ?), you are using, must set OCI_ATTR_DISTINGUISHED_NAME session attribute. If that is not done, then you will be not able to connect to Oracle server using ODI and OCI.

You should check your components documentation for this feature. And if it is not implemented, then discuss this issue with the components vendor. Actually, there is not much work to implement, but some work to setup testing environment is required ...